# Problem with Identifying Complex Components

Tags: complex, assumptions

I am trying to isolate out the real and complex terms in a fairly large expression. During the process, I have made several assumptions that last throughout the entire process.

```
$Assumptions = Element[{x,y},Reals] && {x,y}>0
```

When I try separating the real and complex parts, the `Re` and `Im` functions have trouble with terms where variables appear in the denominator. For example

```
Im[1/(x^2 + 4 y^2)^(9/2)] //Simplify = Im[1/(x^2 + 4 y^2)^(9/2)]
```

Even though all the terms are real and positive, meaning there should be no complex component, and the expression should be zero

I have checked, and if the denominator does not involve two or more terms, `Im` does work successfully. For example

```
Im[1/(x^2)^(9/2) ] //Simplify = 0
Im[1/(4 y^2)^(9/2)] //Simplify = 0
```

Can someone please comment on if this is a bug in the version I have, or am I doing something incorrect here? A mwe is provided below. For reference, I am using version 10.0.0.0

-Thanks

```
In[421]:=
$Assumptions = Element[{x, y}, Reals] && {x, y} > 0 ;
Simplify[Im[1/(x^2 + 4*y^2)^(9/2)]]
Simplify[Im[1/(x^2)^(9/2)]]
Simplify[Im[1/(y^2)^(9/2)]]

Out[424]= Im[1/(x^2+4 y^2)^(9/2)]
Out[425]= 0
Out[426]= 0
```

### Edit

If I modify the assumptions to define each one separately, the code runs fine. e.g

```
$Assumptions = Element[x, Reals] && Element[y, Reals] && x > 0 && y > 0 ;
```

In my main program, I have a large number of variables that are both real and positive, is there a way to assign these all at once, or do I need to do each one separately?

Comment: To the edit: If you have those variables in a list `varlist` then `$Assumptions = And @@ (Element[#, Reals] && # > 0 & /@ varlist)` will do the trick.

Comment: Try `ComplexExpand[Im[...]]`. That should work. Same for the real part

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`{x,y} > 0` is not doing what you think it does. In contrast to [`Element`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Element.html) which, as its documentation states, accepts arbitrary patterns and in which first argument, being a `List` of more than one elements, evaluates to `Alternatives`:

```
$Assumptions = {x, y} ∈ Reals
(* (x | y) ∈ Reals *)
x ∈ Reals // Refine
(* True *)
y ∈ Reals // Refine
(* True *)
```

`{x,y} > 0` in assumptions is just stating that literal list expression `{x, y}` is greater than zero and not that individual elements of list are greater than zero:

```
$Assumptions = {x, y} > 0
(* {x, y} > 0 *)
{x, y} > 0 // Refine
(* True *)
x > 0 // Refine
(* x > 0 *)
y > 0 // Refine
(* y > 0 *)
```

Using expression in inequality in assumptions implies that this expression is real:

```
$Assumptions = x > 0;
x ∈ Reals // Refine
(* True *)
```

For some reason, although `{x, y} > 0` assumption, assumes that only literal list is greater than zero, it also results in individual elements being assumed real:

```
$Assumptions = {x, y} > 0;
{x, y} ∈ Reals // Refine
(* True *)
x ∈ Reals // Refine
(* True *)
y ∈ Reals // Refine
(* True *)
```

---

Going back to expression from question it's enough to assume that individual symbols are greater than zero, this will automatically imply that they are real.

```
$Assumptions = And @@ Thread[{x, y} > 0]
(* x > 0 && y > 0 *)
Im[1/(x^2 + 4*y^2)^(9/2)] // Refine
(* 0 *)
Im[1/(x^2)^(9/2)] // Refine
(* 0 *)
Im[1/(y^2)^(9/2)] // Refine
(* 0 *)
```

Comment: That works exactly like what I was looking for. Thanks for the clear answer

Answer (score 3):

```
$Assumptions = And @@ Thread[Greater[{x, y, d, e}, 0]] && Element[{x, y, d, e}, Reals]
```

> ```
> x > 0 && y > 0 && d > 0 && e > 0 && (x | y | d | e) ∈ Reals
> ```

```
ComplexExpand[Im[1/(y^2)^(9/2)]]
```

> ```
> 0
> ```

Comment: By the way, `Greater[{x, y, d, e}, 0]` is just `{x, y, d, e} > 0` even inside `Thread`

Comment: @ybeltukov, I don't think so. `Greater[{x, y, d, e}, 0] === Thread[Greater[{x, y, d, e}, 0]]` evaluates to flase `False`

Comment: I mean a more obvious thing: `Thread[{x, y, d, e} > 0] === Thread[Greater[{x, y, d, e}, 0]]`