# How to impose Assumptions for a list of variables?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, version-9, assumptions

I've got an $Assumptions variable that I'd like to apply to my whole notebook, looking like so at the moment:

```
$Assumptions = a > 0 && a ∈ Reals && m > 0 && m ∈ Reals ;
```

I've actually got a number of variables, and would like to treat all of them as Real and greater than zero.  Is there a way to apply such assumptions in batch for a set of variables?

EDIT: comments suggested that only the > checks were required, and that {a,m} > 0 can be used.  The greater comment appears to be true, but the set greater than doesn't appear to work:

```
ClearAll[ a, m, x, psi] ;

psi[x_, a_]  = E^(-x^2/2/a^2) / Sqrt[ a Sqrt[Pi]] ;

$Assumptions = a > 0 && a ∈ Reals  ;
Integrate[ psi[x, a]^2, {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]

$Assumptions = a > 0   ;
Integrate[ psi[x, a]^2, {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]

$Assumptions = {a, m} > 0   ;
Integrate[ psi[x, a]^2, {x, -Infinity, Infinity}] // Simplify

Integrate[psi[x, a]^2, {x, -Infinity, Infinity}] // FullSimplify
```

(This gives 1,1, Abs[a]/a, and 1/Sign[a] respectively).

So the question is reduced to how to list a set of variables in Assumptions so that all of them are > 0 (without writing `a > 0 && b > 0 && c > 0 && ...`).

Comment: `a > 0` already implies `a ∈ Reals`, so you only have to include the former assumption.

Comment: $Assumptions = {a, b, c} > 0;
Simplify[Element[b, Reals]] evaluates to True

Comment: Add `//Simplify ` after each operation and you are there. Have fun!

Comment: Tried adding both // Simplify and // FullSimplify (as now mentioned in an update).  Simplify doesn't change the result, and FullSimplify still seems to not know about the a > 0 assumption.

Comment: I can't reproduce the behavior you report. I get `1` for all. Which version are you using? Also, try `Thread[{a,m}>0]` or even `And@@Thread[{a,m}>0]`as a workaround.

Comment: I'm using mathematica 9.0.1.0

Comment: Related: [Problem with Identifying Complex Components](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/99037/14303).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work (based on https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5263/10)

```
ClearAll[a, m, x, psi];

psi[x_, a_] = E^(-x^2/2/a^2)/Sqrt[a Sqrt[Pi]];

$Assumptions = And @@ (# > 0 &) /@ {a, m} ;
Integrate[psi[x, a]^2, {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

One of the comments suggested that `{a,m} > 0` would work, but that doesn't appear to be the case for me (Mathematica 9).

Comment: I can reproduce this with version 9.0.1. `Thread[{a,m}>0]` works though.